# Checkbox input doesn't get centered along with the label

Tags: css, checkbox, bootstrap-4

The `text-center` centers the label "check this custom checkbox" but the input remains on the left.

If you remove that `custom-control-input` class then you will see a new checkbox input which will be centered and the bootstrap input will still be there on the left and it will be unclickable.

I want to center the whole thing.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bootstrap 4.1 or newer like the latest 4.2.1 release. The `custom-control-label` was changed as of Bootstrap 4.1 to be `position:relative` which will allow both the checkbox and label to be centered.

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/gSadshDI2G)

Answer (score 0):

Try this markup:

```
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" />Check this custom checkbox</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code,**

just tell your current div **'d-inline-block'** this is bootstrap class and wrap a container class and add **text-center**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="custom-control d-inline-block custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
</div>
```